# SharePoint office 365 regional settings

Tags: powershell, office-365, microsoft-teams, regional-settings

I am planning to update regional settings in Office 365 for SharePoint site and Microsoft Team site with the following code:

The question is if the Global admin or tenant admin would have ability to update the site or Microsoft team site regional setting. If not what would be the right account or user to run the update regional settings for Office 365 sites and MS Team site?

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#function to change Timezone regional settings of a SharePoint Online site
Function Set-SPOnlineTimeZone([String]$SiteURL,[String]$TimezoneName,[PSCredential]$Cred)
{ 
     Try
     {
        #Setup Credentials to connect
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

        #Set up the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $credentials

        #Get the Root web from given URL
        $Web = $Ctx.web
        $Ctx.Load($Web)

        #Get the Time zone to update
        $Timezones = $Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZones
        $Ctx.Load($Timezones)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $NewTimezone = $Timezones | Where {$_.Description -eq $TimezoneName}

        #Update the timezone of the site
        $Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone = $NewTimezone
        $Web.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        Write-host -f Green "Timezone has been updated for "$Web.Url

        #Get all subsites of the web
        $Ctx.Load($Web.Webs)
        $Ctx.executeQuery()

        #Iterate through each subsites and call the function recursively
        Foreach ($Subweb in $Web.Webs)
        {
            #Call the function to set Timezone for the web
            Set-SPOnlineTimeZone -SiteURL $Subweb.URL -TimezoneName $TimezoneName -Cred $AdminCredentials
        }
   }
    Catch [System.Exception]
    {
        Write-Host -f Red $_.Exception.Message
    } 
} 

#Config parameters for SharePoint Online Admin Center and Timezone description
$AdminSiteURL = "https://crescent-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$TimezoneName ="(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat"

#Get credentials to connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
$AdminCredentials = Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online Tenant Admin
Connect-SPOService -URL $AdminSiteURL -Credential $AdminCredentials

#Get all Site Collections
$SitesCollection = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

#Iterate through each site collection
ForEach($Site in $SitesCollection)
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Setting Timezone for Site Collection:"$Site.URL

    #Call the function to set Timezone for the site
    Set-SPOnlineTimeZone -SiteURL $Site.URL -TimezoneName $TimezoneName -cred $AdminCredentials
}
```

url:https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/06/sharepoint-online-change-time-zone-using-powershell.html